# Disable input fields on check box checked

Tags: python, html, django

In html page I am using `{{form.fieldname}}` to fetch check box in model.

I have a checkbox field in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models


cr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and in html page I have:

```
{{form.cr}}
Continuous Rx<br>
```

How can I disable text field on checkbox check?

Comment: You need to update your question with more information.

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: thank you so much , that helped .